# Logging in with Google or Google+?

Tags: discussion

I use quite a few computers, and I use my Google account to log in. Every time I do so, I've noticed the button to do so reads "Google +". As far as I know, I've never created a Google plus account, so I'm wondering what the difference is, or if there is any.

Image:

[image: http://imgur.com/VfINLG8]

Comment: It is just branding, Google trying to push their social networking.  It is njetworking, Google+ has been pronounced dead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no practical difference from a Single-Sign-On perspective. Google logins work for all Google products and such.

You do have to have opted into Google+ to use that service, however.